# How can I map this HTML (table of checkboxes) into MVC ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know how to map individual checkboxes into MVC ViewModel like:

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OnlyThisNetwork)
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OnlyThisNetwork)and 

[DisplayName("Only this network")]
        public bool OnlyThisNetwork { get; set; }
```

But what about this table of checkboxes? I can't figure out to do it.

```
<table>
<thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="add">Frequency/Format</th>
                                <th>All</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Mobile</th>
                                <th>Social</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="add">As it happens</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="add">Once a week</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="add">Once a month</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" title="bike" id="social" class="checkbox"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Can anyone help? I changed the post to reflect the MVC code I am binding to.

Comment: Your first example wouldn't bind correctly and it seems to me that you want radios instead of checkboxes.

Comment: The first example is working code. As for this, the customer wants checkboxes just like the supllied HTML.

Comment: Well now you've edited the code to work. And what would you expect to happen when someone selects "All" "As it happens" and "Email" "Once a week"? The customer probably doesn't understand the difference between a radio and checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `name` attribute for all checkboxes and set the `value` attribute for each. Then you'll get an array with the selected values:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='items' value='item1' />
<input type='checkbox' name='items' value='item2' />
<input type='checkbox' name='items' value='item3' />
```

In the controller you can have the post method getting an array of strings (you can have other types if the values can be converted with the actual model binder):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckItems(String[] items)
{
    ...use the values...
}
```

You can have the array in your model object and it will be used (if the name corresponds with the property name of the array).

Comment: But I don't want to use <input>. I want use Html.CheckboxFor

Comment: You can try this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356703/create-mvc3-checkboxfor-from-listt-and-getting-the-list-back-with-updated-val but I think it's easier doing it using the input tags.

Comment: Use `Html.Checkbox("items")`